# Anaconda install error in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, anaconda

I downloaded the "Anaconda-2.4.2-Linux-x86_64.sh" from its website,
but when I wanted to install it by putting 
"bash Anaconda-2.4.2-Linux-x86_64.sh" in the terminal, 
it failed and told me 
"ERROR:the size of Anaconda-2.4.2-Linux-x86_64.sh should be 467689464 bytes".

I had tried google, but there is no answer.

Comment: try, `chmod +x Anaconda-2.4.2-Linux-x86_64.sh; ./Anaconda-2.4.2-Linux-x86_64.sh`

Comment: download again - maybe file is broken

Comment: What @furas said.

Comment: That  did work,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download again the file Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh as indicated by @furas

at:

> https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

The size of the file have to be: 467689464 bytes

[image]

And just press Enter to install: